# How to password protect an application in Android

Tags: android, password-protection

I want the user to enter a password everytime he tries to enter the application. That is, the user must enter the password everytime the app comes to foreground from background, be it by pressing the **launcher icon** or **long-pressing the home key**

I sort-of achieved the first part because the launcher intent is fired and i get a callback in onRestart of that activity.

But by long-pressing home key and launching the does not provide callback to onRestart.

Also what if the user launches the app by pressing the **notification** from, the notification bar. How do I distinguish whether the app was originally in background or fore-ground before the user clicked the notification

Comment: "onRestart" - you mean onResume()?

Comment: by onRestart I mean onRestart and not onResume, because onResume will eventually be called after onStart

Answer (score 1):

In your `onResume` call, set a `loginCounter` += 1, in your `onPause` -= 1.

if loginCounter == 0 => show Login Dialog.

In the Notification Bar you set an `Intent` to call the `Activity`, correct? Simply add a parameter "isCalledByNotificationBar" as boolean in there.

Comment: On a sidenote: You cannot ever overwrite the behavior of the HomeKey. It's only possible if you modify the Android sourcecode and deploy it on your target device (unlikely).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but consider this situation. I launch activity A1, so on its onResume **loginCounter = 1**. Now from A1 I launch A2, A1's on pause is called making loginCounter = 0. So now after every activity launch I get a password prompt. Moreover if any other dialog is shown over A1 it will lead showing the password dialog. I hope you get the problem

Comment: But you said yourself that "the user must enter the password everytime the app comes to foreground from background" which is exactly what is happening in that case.

Comment: @frieza: regarding "So now after every activity launch I get a password prompt": start each activity with an extra like 'nopasswd' passed to the intent (intent.putExtra(). If this extra exists, you don't ask for a password, otherwise you do. In onCreate you clear the extra param so it doesn't exist anymore in case the device goes to sleep or the screen goes back into foreground after home long-press. Haven't tried, just a thought.

Comment: @Chris: I want the user to enter a password everytime my app goes to the background not everytime a new activity is launched  @Mathias: your solution should work perfectly, except for the following situation. A user is using my app, a notification from my app appears. The user pulls down the drawer and clicks on my notification which takes him to another activity. But if my app is in background and the user attends to my notification then I must prompt him for password. How does the above solution handle it

Comment: I think what you are missing is that "clicks on my notification which takes him to another activity" means that the original activity is now in the background.

Comment: @Chris: exactly so. Consider this, my original activity is in background both when the app is in background and when the user clicks my notification while he was on the original activity. Now I would like the user to be prompted for password in the first case and not in the later. So how do I distinguish between these two cases ?

Comment: As you can't reliably tell what the foreground activity is, the only thing I can think of is the timeout timer idea I posted separately, just reset it every time you are in some piece of your code, and if you get back to some piece of your code before it expires, assume the user didn't "mean to" "really" leave.  Then tune the delay until this is sufficiently true.

Comment: chris, it seems the timer idea is the only thing which might help. I will implement it until a better implementation surfaces. thanks a ton for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

If `onResume` doesn't work, how about `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)`?

Comment: sorry I did not get what I should do in onResume which now you're advising me to do onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you should do is on re-entry into the application see if it's been less than 30 (?) seconds since a timestamp that you update when any activity of your application was last paused.  If it's been less, don't ask for a password.  Thinking being that this short time window might smooth over some transitions you don't want to log out on.